# How to calculate confidence level from confidence interval?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

A simple random sample of size 10 from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ gives $98$% confidence interval$(20.49,23.51)$. The null hypothesis is $H_0: \mu=20.5$ against $H_1: \mu \ne20.5$.

What will be the confidence level for accepting this hypothesis?
I am trying to solve this problem but unable to understand how to extract confidence level from the interval,Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

It says that it is a $98\%$ confidence interval, so the confidence is $98\%$. If you mean

> What is the **significance** level?

Then this is a $98\%$ CI $\iff$$(1-\alpha)\%$ CI. This implies that the significance level is $\alpha = 1-.98 = .02$.

Comment: Does that mean that the null hypothesis can be rejected at 2% level of significance

Comment: If I recall correctly, since $\mu = 20.5$ is contained in your $98\%$ CI, then there is not enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis at significance level $\alpha = .02$.

Comment: does that mean that if 100 samples are taken then 98 would get its mean from CI and 2 times it would be out of CI but we want to so would the significance level for rejecting the null hypothesis$=0.98 \times$ probability of not getting $\mu=20.5$?

Comment: [This site](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/understanding-hypothesis-tests%3A-significance-levels-alpha-and-p-values-in-statistics) might be a good place to start reading about $\alpha.$

Comment: Thanx, but can you tell me just the answer of my question in the comment

Comment: If you take 100 samples, then you expect about 98 of the confidence intervals you construct to contain $\mu = 20.5$ **at significance level** $\alpha = .02$. What you are saying about multiplying doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okk....Now i'm tired ....i really need to read about $\alpha$ thanx